# Latin-derived terms for directions

Tags: latin

If dextrad, sinistrad, and mediad mean towards the right, left, and middle respectively, what would the related terms be for up and down/top and bottom?

Comment: those terms are unfamiliar to me. What area of expertise are these used in? (that may give a clue as to what the ones you're looking for are)

Comment: @Mitch those are (rather rarely used) medical terms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for either *[cephalad](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/cephalad)* and *[caudad](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/caudad)*:

> **cephalad**, adjective. Referring to the direction of the head; towards the head. Cephalad is being increasingly replaced by “toward the head” in the working medical parlance.

(Segen's Medical Dictionary, via TheFreeDictionary.com)

> **caudad**, directed toward the tail or distal end; opposite of cephalad.
>   (Miller-Keane Encyclopedia and Dictionary of Medicine, Nursing, and Allied Health, Seventh Edition; via TheFreeDictionary.com)

or perhaps *[dorsad](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/dorsad)* and *[ventrad](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/ventrad)*:

> **dorsad**, toward the back.

(Miller-Keane Encyclopedia and Dictionary of Medicine, Nursing, and Allied Health, Seventh Edition; via TheFreeDictionary.com)

> **ventrad**, toward a belly, venter or ventral aspect.

(Miller-Keane Encyclopedia and Dictionary of Medicine, Nursing, and Allied Health, Seventh Edition; via TheFreeDictionary.com)

Which pair you pick depends on what nominal direction the body is facing.

Note: *cephalad* is Greek in origin; the others are Latin.

Comment: Also 
 Antrorse :

bent or directed forward or upward. (New Latin antrōrsum, from Latin anterior)